# Annotate points in Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to annotate points on a plot using the coordinates in the list `I5`. But running into an error. The expected output is attached.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

I5 = [[(0.5, -0.5), (1.5, -0.5)], [(0.5, -0.5), (0.5, -1.5)], [(1.5, -0.5), (1.5, -1.5)], [(0.5, -1.5), (1.5, -1.5)]]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

N=3   #len(inv_r)+1
X = np.arange(0,N,1)
Y = -X

for i in range(len(I5)):
    plt.annotate(I5[0][i])

x_sorted = np.sort(X)
y_sorted = np.sort(Y)
ax.set_xticks(x_sorted)
ax.set_yticks(y_sorted)
ax.set_xlim(x_sorted[0], x_sorted[-1])
ax.set_ylim(y_sorted[0], y_sorted[-1])
ax.grid()
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
plt.show()
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    plt.annotate(I5[0][i])

  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py", line 335, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: annotate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'xy'
```

The expected output is

[image]

Comment: I5 is the annotation string? I need the coordinates of each xy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

I5 = [[(0.5, -0.5), (0.5, -0.5)], [(0.5, -1.5), (0.5, -1.5)], [(1.5, -0.5), (1.5, -0.5)], [(1.5, -1.5), (1.5, -1.5)]]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

N=3   #len(inv_r)+1
X = np.arange(0,N,1)
Y = -X

for i in range(0,len(I5)):
    plt.annotate(I5[i][0],I5[i][1])

x_sorted = np.sort(X)
y_sorted = np.sort(Y)
ax.set_xticks(x_sorted)
ax.set_yticks(y_sorted)
ax.set_xlim(x_sorted[0], x_sorted[-1])
ax.set_ylim(y_sorted[0], y_sorted[-1])
ax.grid()
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
plt.show()
```

In the `I5` list the first tuple is the text you want to plot and the second tuple is the coordinates where you plot the text. I don't know if you want to add point but if you want to, you delete the first tuple to have only the coordinates tuple and then go

```
plt.plot(cord_tuple[0](x),cord_tuple[1](y))
plt.show()
```